# Declare upper bound of int for initial declaration in Java?

Tags: java, list, for-loop, comparison

I am trying to use a `for` loop to compare the differences between `int`s in an `ArrayList`. Therefore I need to have an arbitrarily large initial variable for which any difference must be less than. Here is the minimal viable example:

```
List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<>();
l.add(5);
l.add(1);
// ...etc

Collections.sort(l);
int diff = 0;
int minDiff = 100;

for (int i = 1; i < l.size(); i++) {
    diff = l.get(i) - l.get(i-1);
    if (diff < minDiff) minDiff = diff;
}
```

My problem is in the case where `diff` is greater than `minDiff`, in this case, if it was `> 100`. Is there a solution which assigns `minDiff` such that any other `int` is less than it? Thanks!

Comment: Note that in the general case, a difference of two integers `a-b` can overflow, so the safest way to compare a difference of `int`s is to subtract as `long`. In other words, `long diff = (long) l.get(i) - (long) l.get(i-1);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd set it to the largest integer value possible:

```
int minDiff = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
```

Everything will be smaller when compared to it.

Comment: Alternatively, initialize `minDiff = l.get(1) - l.get(0)`. But since that duplicates the logic in the loop, your way is preferable.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you don't need to think about the initial value of `diff` in case you assign it as the difference between two initial values of the `List<Integer> l`. And increment the initial iteration index `i` to `2`.

```
int minDiff = 100;

int diff = l.get(1) - l.get(0);
for (int i = 2; i < l.size(); i++) {

    diff = l.get(i) - l.get(i-1);
    if (diff < minDiff) minDiff = diff;
}
```

This solution suggests that the list contains at least `3` elements.

---

Alternatively, give Stream-API a try which fully replaces the `for-loop` and the helper variable `diff`:

```
int minDiff = IntStream.range(0, l.size() - 1))                       // 0...n-1 iteration
                       .map(index -> l.get(index + 1) - l.get(index)) // output differences
                       .min().getAsInt();                             // finds the minimum
```

Answer (score 0):

Using streams:

```
int minDiff = IntStream.range(1, l.size())
    .map(i -> l.get(i) - l.get(i-1))
    .mapToInt()
    .min().getAsInt();
```

Comment: I'm new to Java, so I have yet to learn Streams - do I simply replace my for loop with that code?